# How do I remove a document from an api payload?

Tags: json, underscore.js

how do i remove a document in underscore js?

i have this collection from a response in an api

```
I20150707-21:43:38.217(8)?{ next: 'https://cloudalytics-api-phx.prod.jivehosted.com:443/analytics/v2/export/activity/lastday?startIndex=100&count=100',
I20150707-21:43:38.217(8)?   itemsPerPage: 100,
I20150707-21:43:38.217(8)?   totalCount: 177687,
I20150707-21:43:38.217(8)?   currentPage: 1,
I20150707-21:43:38.217(8)?   totalPages: 1777 }
I20150707-21:43:38.315(8)? [ { name: 'ACTIVITY_PEOPLE_SEARCH',
I20150707-21:43:38.315(8)?     timestamp: 1436276604627,
I20150707-21:43:38.315(8)?     context: { web: [Object] },
I20150707-21:43:38.315(8)?     payload: { KEYWORDS_PARAM: 'old emails*' },
I20150707-21:43:38.316(8)?     actorID: 1174358,
I20150707-21:43:38.316(8)?     actorType: 3,
I20150707-21:43:38.316(8)?     activityType: 'People',
I20150707-21:43:38.316(8)?     actionObjectId: -1,
I20150707-21:43:38.316(8)?     actionObjectType: 109,
I20150707-21:43:38.317(8)?     activity: 
I20150707-21:43:38.317(8)?      { actor: [Object],
I20150707-21:43:38.317(8)?        action: 'People',
I20150707-21:43:38.317(8)?        actionObject: [Object],
I20150707-21:43:38.317(8)?        activityTime: 1436276604627 } },...etc
```

and i want to remove the 1st document `{next,...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to remove the 1st document without using the underscore.js

in an `API call` there are response that have different json format [json api](http://jsonapi.org/) . in my case, you just dont have to include the some resources that you dont need.

feel free to edit.